# Which class deals more damage?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I still have my 90 boost left and I want to use it either on a mage or a priest. So I am asking myself, which class deals more damage (DPS) on single targets (e.g. SoO bosses)?

Lots of people told me that a frost mage is easier to play and deals more damage but if both classes are fully geared up (heroic SoO) and the player is experienced the shadow priest will deal way more damage, although I've never got an evidence for that (for example recount log, rotation etc.).

Comment: as a priest you have more choices and you can level as healer in instances. As mage (i was mage) you have only and easy rotations and you shoot fireballs from far away. Damage is high but fun is low after some time.

Comment: Isn't this highly opinion-based? I mean, is there a definite, *correct* answers to this?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I agree. Could also be too broad given how many patches, classes and styles of boss fights that WoW has.

Comment: And the word "better" would probably need a very specific definition in this context as well. I mean, is it better to do extreme burst damage but have survivability like a bird in a cardboard armor? Or will lower DPS be better, provided you can live longer? Personally I have better luck doing DPS if I'm alive so a nice balance is always useful, but there's so many combinations of gear and skills that getting a *definitive* answer out of this is probably impossible.

Comment: I accept that. But can you please put it on hold as too broad, because it's definitely not opinion based.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question since it's clearly answerable through Playing experience and Statistics/Simulation analysis.

Comment: @Jutschge Answerability makes a poor metric to decide if a question should remain open or not.  Rather focus on why the question was closed in the first place.  Yeah, you can answer it, but that doesn't mean it's not opinion based.

Comment: @Frank It's answerable based on facts. That does make a difference when it's closed as POB.

Comment: @Frank Then please explain, how is this question opinion based? How is damage defined by blizzard a players opinion?

Comment: I didn't close it; you'll have to ask those that did.  I do think that it's too broad, and will close it as such if it does get reopened, though.  There are too many factors and variables for any answer to properly answer this.  I'm just saying, being able to answer a question should never be part of the process of whether or not to reopen a question.  There's lots of questions that are answerable that we don't allow.

Comment: @Frank Yeah sure but I feel like WoW is a special game here. While yes usually in games questions like this are extremely hard/broad to answer, in WoW you have a lot of tools and players that focus solely on Theorycrafting. It's one of the most important aspects in the game especially in High-Level Competitive play.

Comment: Yeah I already said I'm ok with that, apparently this question is a bit too big to be here.

Comment: If one class deals more damage Blizzard will nerf it. Just play whatever class you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty hard to tell what will actually deal "more" damage in current raids since there are a lot of boss-mechanics that can influence your damage. Another big factor is your playstyle preference.

Most people are not able to play every class perfectly, so maybe you will deal more DPS with a priest just because you like the playstyle more.

Now to the real question: Who deals more damage? If you take a look at the [simulationcraft results](http://www.simulationcraft.org/reports/Raid_T16H.html) you can see that the mage is one of the top Dps classes while the shadow Priest is at the bottom of the list. However keep in mind that Simcraft is a simulation for **5 minute long Patchwork fights that are perfectly executed**. So these simulation results don't explicitly say that the Mage is superior to a Shadow Priest.

Mages are great for raw DPS and they also have a Heroism Raid CD but Shadow Priests are one of the best classes (if not the best) for multidotting in raids while they also provide a lot of raid utility with their heal and they can soak up a lot more damage than a mage with their dispersion.

In the end it's personal preference what you want to max. Maybe you are performing better with a DoT based class (SP) or maybe you like bursting and Casting more (mage).

As a small subjective input: I think Mages are easier to learn than Shadow Priests so if you're not familiar with the classes, maybe it's better to use the boost on the mage but in the end if you plan to perfectly play a class it's basically the same difficulty and it needs a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess this question doesn't get reopened / closed "correctly", so I accepted your answer. A friend is currently doing own researches since he has a mage and a priest with similar equipment. I'll share the results as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

That depends: **Which patch are we talking about?**

The thing about the various classes in WoW is that Blizzard is constantly buffing/nerfing different classes each patch. There is no consistent *best* damage dealer if you look at even a timeframe of a couple of months. When the new expansion comes out, expect classes to be reworked. When a patch comes out after that, expect the classes to be further changed. I've been playing since Burning Crusades, and I have seen every class take its fair share of the spotlight.

In that regard, **just play the class that you'll have the most fun with**. That may be a hybrid class if you would also like to tank or heal, or you may even have multiple top-level classes that you switch between. Sure class A might not currently be as strong as class B, but it's not really going to matter for most game content. The only time that I have seen this matter is in cases where a guild is looking for a specific raid composition for bleeding edge progression, but that's a special case and can be largely ignored by most people.